# How to avoid select with copy named Range and paste as link?

Tags: excel, vba

How to avoid select with copy named Range and paste as link , as in the below code

```
Sub Paste_Named_Range()

If Sheet03.[G60] = "3rd Q" Then

    Sheet03.[Quarter_1].Copy
    Sheet03.[O68].Select
    Sheet03.Paste Link:=True

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet03.[O68].Paste`, avoiding select

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I need to paste as a link , and I already read that great post.

Comment: What about `Sheet03.[O68].Paste Link:=True`?

Comment: It gives error "syntax error"

Comment: Posted an answer but it does not really helps. I upvoted the question and let's see if maybe other user helps out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy a Simple Formula Instead of `Paste Link:=True`

- The following will work properly only if `Quarter_1` is a contiguous (single) range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Paste_Named_Range()
    
    ' Works only for a contiguous (single) range (a range with one area).
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet03.[Quarter_1] ' .Areas(1)
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = Sheet03.[O68].Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    If Sheet03.[G60] = "3rd Q" Then
        drg.Formula = "=" & srg.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case. **Because you are using the Link argument = True**, I'm afraid you must first select the destination.

> [Worksheet.Paste method
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste)

In the documentation about *Link*:

> True to establish a link to the source of the pasted data. **If this
> argument is specified, the Destination argument cannot be used**. The
> default value is False.

And because we are forced to omit the *Destination* argument, then:

> **If this argument is omitted, the current selection is used**. This
> argument can be specified only if the contents of the Clipboard can be
> pasted into a range.

Because all of this, **I'm afraid you can't avoid Select in this case**. So your code should be exactly as you have it:

```
Sheet03.[Quarter_1].Copy
Sheet03.[O68].Select
Sheet03.Paste Link:=True
```

Good question. I did not know about this fact. Let's see if maybe other user can help you out, but after reading documentation, I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

What about avoiding copy/paste

```vb
Sub Paste_Named_Range()

If Sheet03.[G60] = "3rd Q" Then
    Sheet03.[O68].Formula = "=Quarter_1"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dose, not work at all

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work at all"? Do you get an error? Is the result not as expected? The result should be "= Quarter_1" as a formula in cell O68 ...

Comment: It insert Quarter_1 as string , I even modified it ( corrected) but not works also

Comment: Again: what does not work? If you type manually "= Quarter_1" into the cell - does it show the correct value? Or is my understanding not correct that Quarter_1 is a named cell?